# Laravel validate array element is required if array is present

Tags: php, laravel, validation

Laravel 5.7. I have a form request validation for a model `Foo`. The model has an optional field `bar`, which must be an array. If it is present, it must contain two keys, `bing` and `bang`. But if the array is absent, obviously these two keys should not be validated.

This is what I have so far:

```
return [
    'bar'      => 'bail|array|size:2',
    'bar.bing' => 'required|numeric',
    'bar.bang' => 'required|numeric',
];
```

This works when I send a request with the `bar` array present. But when I send a request without the `bar` array, I still get the validation errors

> The bar.bing field is required
>
> The bar.bang field is required

How can I make them only required when `bar` is present?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with this rules

```
return [
    'bar'      => 'nullable|bail|array|size:2',
    'bar.bing' => 'required_with:bar|numeric',
    'bar.bang' => 'required_with:bar|numeric',
]
```

[Docs for `required_with`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-required-with)

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. I edited your answer to add a link to the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I tend to do in this sort of situations

```php
public function rules(): array
{
    $rules = [
        // ...
    ];

    if ($this->bar) {
        $rules['bar'] = 'array|size:2';
        $rules['bar.bing'] = 'required|numeric';
        $rules['bar.bang'] = 'required|numeric';
    }

    return $rules;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thought about that but would love it if there was a more encapsulated way of doing it.

Comment: You could try conditional `sometimes` rule, but I never tried with the array keys and haven't seen any encapsulating approach for this sort of scenario.